# Problems with FIPS Mode in Adobe Acrobat Pro 2020 and Adobe Reader DC

Tags: security, windows-10, windows-registry, fips-140-2, adobe-acrobat

Security requirements are such that we need to set this key depending on software:

HKCU\Software\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\2020\AVGeneral\bFIPSMode (DWORD = 1)

KHCU\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\DC\AVGeneral\bFIPSMode (DWORD = 1)

This was done successfully, but we find periodic issues with certain forms our organization distributes throwing this error:

[image: Error]

This happens when the form is saved after editing.  The consistency appears to be that they are all forms that permid digitial signature, but this error does not only happen when the form is signed (i.e. we can take the blank form, type a single random letter in some field, and see that it fails to save).

We can typically resolve it if we set the DWORD back to 0 on the impacted hosts, but this is not a long term solution.

Going by what I found online this might have something to do with the form itself, perhaps being password protected at some point, but it is not something we have set on the form nor is it something we're required to perform (i.e. we aren't prompted for a password on these forms at any time).  Otherwise I have no leads.

Has anyone experienced this issue previously, and if so what solution did you find to resolve it?